# How to get the link database using sitecore.services.client item service?

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I'm trying to get the links for an item using item services.

For this, I need to query the link database.

Can anyone tried querying link database using Sitecore.services.client item service?

```
ex :
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://<your server>/sitecore/api/ssc/item/110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9/children");
```

Comment: It is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get any information from the Link Database using Sitecore Services Client (ItemService).

As the documentation states ( https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-itemservice.html ):

> The ItemService provides a single HTTP endpoint and an API that you use to interact with Sitecore items over HTTP.

You can only interact with items, not with the whole Sitecore API.

> Sitecore.Services.Client maps Sitecore items into instances of Sitecore.Services.Core.Model.ItemModel when the ItemService returns them.

You can only get items by ID, by path or by search query, but you cannot use all the Sitecore API methods which are available when you write custom code in your Sitecore application.